# Browser is preventing Windows screensaver from starting. How can I disable that?

Tags: browser, screensaver

I'm using a tablet to show security cameras. I want the screen to stay on, but I want it to go blank after a few minutes to prevent screen burn in. The problem is that my web-based camera viewer seems to trigger the browsers "I'm watching a video" function that disables the screensaver from activating. How can I disable that function so the screensaver comes on after a period of inactivity regardless of what's in the browser?

The browser doesn't matter. I can use any browser since the cameras are showing on a URL.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1816293/using-ispy-agent-dvr-software-to-load-up-a-browser-with-my-home-cameras-but-it#comment2855380_1816293